# How to understand the code "cc[bb] += aa" in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

```
import torch
aa=torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).T
bb=torch.tensor([0,1,1]).T
cc = torch.zeros(2, 2)
cc[bb] += aa
```

Then the result is `cc=tensor([[1., 4.],[3., 6.]])`, why?

Comment: Which parts of that do you understand? Have you inspected the state of `aa`, `bb` and `cc` before that statement?

Comment: I got the same result when moving `aa`, `bb`, `cc` to gpu. This is quite strange for me, since I think the `add` operator should be conducted in parallel on gpu. I suppose I should get one of  `cc=tensor([[1., 4.],[2., 5.]])`  and `cc=tensor([[1., 4.],[3., 6.]])` randomly. However, I always get `cc=tensor([[1., 4.],[3., 6.]])`. This just seems like applying `cc[bb[1]]=aa[1]` first and then applying `cc[bb[2]]=aa[2]`, which invalidates the influence of `cc[bb[1]]=aa[1]`.

Comment: And I think perhaps one may get even `cc=tensor([[1., 4.],[5., 11.]])`, which means `cc[bb[2]]=cc[bb[2]]+aa[2]` and `cc[bb[1]]=cc[bb[1]]+aa[1]` are applied one after another. (Sort of race condition problem togethered with `cc=tensor([[1., 4.],[2., 5.]])` and `cc=tensor([[1., 4.],[3., 6.]])`) However, it seems that only `cc[bb[2]]=cc[bb[2]]+aa[2]` is applied.

Answer (score 2):

Let us reason with pseudo code:

```
>>> aa = [[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6]].T
>>> aa
[[1,4],
 [2,5],
 [3,6]]

>>> bb = [0,1,1].T
>>> b
[0,
 1,
 1]

>>> cc = zeros(2, 2)
>>> cc
[[0,0],
 [0,0]]
```

The next instruction is an assignment which consists in first indexing `cc` with `bb` values. Here we are picking entire rows from `cc` using indices in `bb`. Since there are three rows in `bb`, the resulting tensor will consist of `cc[bb[0]]`, `cc[bb[1]]`, and `cc[bb[2]]` but `bb[1]` and `bb[2]` are equal which means it comes down to `cc[0]` and `cc[1]`.

The right-hand side operand is `aa` and consists of three rows: `[1,4]`, `[2,5]`, and `[3,6]`. This means that the final operation performed will be equivalent to (row-wise):

```
cc[0] += [1,4]
cc[1] += [3,6]
```

Since `cc` is initialized with zero values, we can sum this up to:

```
>>> cc[0] = [1,4]
>>> cc[1] = [3,6]
```

This means that:

```
>>> cc
[[1,4],
 [3,6]]
```

Comment: I wonder why `cc[bb[2]]=aa[2]` takes effect, while `cc[bb[1]]=aa[1]` does not. In other word, why `cc[1]=aa[2]` instead of  `cc[1]=aa[1]`? The `cc[bb] += aa` will result in both operation, why does the `cc[1]=aa[2]` disable `cc[1]=aa[1]`? How is the compuation graph of the `torch.add` constructed?